# class not getting instantiated, doesn't work using actionlistener, works fine separately

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, instantiation, awtrobot

I am trying to make a screen capturing program.

What I have is a transparent window, which will give the area to be captured, with a button `capture` on it, and I am trying to instantiate a class `captureScreen` that works good when is individually executed in a seperate file using a `command prompt`.

I am trying to instantiate this `captureScreen` class when button `capture` is hit.
But this doesn't work.
And keeping the `captureScreen.java` separate does nothing when instantiated from this file as

```
captureScreen a = new captureScreen();
```

`System.out.println("Start");` would even not print anything, though it works perfect when run from `command prompt` as

```
java captureScreen
```

Here is `screenrecord.java`

```
public class screenrecord extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public screenrecord() {....}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if ("record".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            captureScreen a = new captureScreen();

            System.out.println("Donesssssss");
        } 
    }   
}

class captureScreen extends Object{

    public int captureScreen(){
        ...
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filename));
        System.out.println("Done");
        return 1;}
        catch(AWTException ex)
        {   
            System.out.println("Error"+ex);
            return 1;
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {   
            System.out.println("Error"+ex);
            return 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public int captureScreen(){` is not a constructor, it is a method, so calling `captureScreen a = new captureScreen()` won't activate this method.

### You could...

Change it so that it is a constructor

```
public captureScreen() {...}
```

### Or you could...

Call the method...

```
captureScreen a = new captureScreen();
a.captureScreen();
```

Now.  Welcome to one of the reasons why you should be following the [naming conventions for the Java language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), because you would have being able to tell the difference between a method and a constructor if you had...

ie  Classes are named starting with an upper case character ie `CaptureScreen`, which makes the constructors follow the same naming `public CaptureScreen(){...}` and methods start with a lower case character.

Just saying

Comment: Okay. This works perfectly. I would accept your answer. But why couldn't I get this working when I kept it in a separate file? I had captureScreen as main function there.

Comment: I was using it the same way , yes may be. `captureScreen a = new captureScreen();`..
In that case what is the correct method to instantiate that class(in a different file).

Comment: The same as instantiating any class, so long as the imports are correct if the class exists in another package.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No the class was in same package. Let me try and tell you if it works. Thanks for making this work till here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No it doesn't work. I just commented the class in this file `screenrecorder`, and imported trial.captureScreen, but no didn't get any screenshot neither the "Start" got printed.

Comment: Can you show use the code you were using when it worked from the command line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32133/discussion-between-optim-and-madprogrammer)

Answer (score 0):

The class captureScreen having code like

```
public int captureScreen(){..}
```

If you considered this as a constructor then don't use return type.

```
public captureScreen(){..}
```

If you considered this as a method then try to call this method from actionPerformed.

```
captureScreen a = new captureScreen();
a.captureScreen();
```